# Match ordered table of regex to text

Tags: python, regex, pandas

Trying to match a large table (1,500 expressions) of complex regex (lots of lookaheads and lookbehinds) to a large pandas data frame (1bn rows) of text data as efficiently as possible, and return an ID for the matched regex expression.

Sample regex:

```
regex = pd.DataFrame({'matchregex' : ['(^(?!.*?(external|internal)).*?(test string))',
                                      '(^(?!.*?(big|small)).*?(testing string))',
                                      '(^(?=.*?(automatic|internal)).*(string (one|two)))'],
                     'id' : [1,2,3]})
```

Sample data:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'ID' : [1,2,3,4],
                     'TextString' : ['External Test String','123 Test String','Automatic String One','String two']})
```

Desired output is a new dataframe containing the ID, and TextString and matching ID from the regex dataframe.

I have tried this approach - https://toltman.medium.com/matching-multiple-regex-patterns-in-pandas-121d6127dd47

However, it extracts match groups and as there are match groups within each expression it tends to throw the wrong thing. It is also extremely slow.

Ideally I would avoid doing a cartesian join between the tables and then comparing the string against each expression as the interim data would be over 1 tn records. Best case would be once the first expression in the order has been matched to a string, it would then ignore the remaining expressions for that record.

Comment: It would be better if you can share, what you have tried till now.

Comment: Thanks @PoojaSonkar - I've added a link above to what was tried. I've also tried using a sql environment to do the matching, but have yet to find a way to avoid comparing all strings against all expressions. Due to the complex regex expression my options seem to be limited.

Answer (score 1):

You could try if this is more efficient:

```
import re

ids = [1,2,3]
patterns = ['(^(?!.*?(external|internal)).*?(test string))',
            '(^(?!.*?(big|small)).*?(testing string))',
            '(^(?=.*?(automatic|internal)).*(string (one|two)))']

regexes = {i: re.compile(pattern, re.IGNORECASE)
           for i, pattern in zip(ids, patterns)}

def check(s):
    for i, pattern in regexes.items():
        if pattern.search(s):
            return i
    return 0

data['Match'] = data.TextString.map(check)
```

Result (`print(data)`):

```
   ID            TextString  Match
0   1  External Test String       0
1   2       123 Test String       1
2   3  Automatic String One       3
3   4            String two       0
```

In `check` I have usesd `0` instead of `None` as return for a null result to avoid casting the `Match` column to `float`. Change it, if you don't like it this way.

Comment: Thank you! This is perfect - works out at about 110 seconds for 10k records, and will be able to scale and parallelize.